# How to read image from .ml file/ Python/tkinter

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter

I need to read the image of a file that has the format .ml from a column in the format of a DATE and a place. Is it in tkinter's widget bitmap image? How do you do it?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: A small program to work with mssql databases